# TypeScript record and play raw pcm audio

Tags: typescript, web-audio-api, audiocontext, web-mediarecorder

I am new to TypeScript, and the whole JavaScript environment in general. I have a small project to do, which requires creating a browser application with TypeScript (*I don't have any code yet*).

I need to record raw PCM audio from the browser microphone, log it, and play the same PCM audio back through browser speakers.

I have looked into using MediaRecorder for recording, and using the plain HTMLAudioElement for playback, but i'm not sure if they support RAW audio. I also some posts mentioning to use AudioContext ScriptProcessorNode to obtain raw audio, but i have no idea how to play them back.

I do not need completed solutions, but would appreciate any pointers or tutorials that would help me get this done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do work on a little library called [extendable-media-recorder](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/extendable-media-recorder) which allows to extend the native MediaRecorder with custom encoders. The proof-of-concept encoder that I build is a WAV encoder. It hope that works for you as well.

I haven't documented the library yet which is why I'm happy to take your question as an opportunity to put together a complete usage example.

```
import { MediaRecorder, register } from 'extendable-media-recorder';
import { connect } from 'extendable-media-recorder-wav-encoder';

(async () => {
    // Get the port a worker which can encode WAV files.
    const port = await connect();
    // Register this port with the MediaRecorder.
    await register(port);
    // Request a MediaStream with an audio track.
    const mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({ audio: true });
    // Create a MediaRecorder instance with the newly obtained MediaStream.
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream, {
        mimeType: 'audio/wav'
    });

    // Kick off the recording.
    mediaRecorder.start();

    mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', ({ data }) => {
        // The data variable now holds a refrence to a Blob with the WAV file.
    });

    // Stop the recording after a second.
    setTimeout(() => mediaRecorder.stop(), 1000);
})();
```

I hope the comments do explain what the code does. Please let me know, if that's not the case.