# Problems installing and importing npm package 'extendable-media-recorder'

Tags: javascript, npm-install, wav, web-audio-api, npm-scripts

As I said in the comment below, I tried to write a web application using the packages 'extendable-media-recorder' and 'extendable-media-recorder-wav-encoder', to be able to encode the sound recorded in the wav format.

Here follows the final version of the Javascript code of the application, after some modifications. Thanks a lot to Chris Guttandin for the libraries and for the help!

```
import { MediaRecorder, register } from 'extendable-media-recorder';
import { connect } from 'extendable-media-recorder-wav-encoder';

const record = document.getElementById('record');
const stop = document.getElementById('stop');  
const soundClips = document.querySelector('.sound-clips');

(async () => {
    const port = await connect();
    await register(port);

 if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    console.log('getUserMedia supported.');
     
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })

    // Success callback
    .then(function(stream) {
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
        mimeType: 'audio/wav'
    });

    record.onclick = function() {      
        var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
        const audioContext = new AudioContext();
  
        mediaRecorder.start();
          console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
          console.log("recorder started");
          record.style.background = "red";
          record.style.color = "black";
        }

      let chunks = [];

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
      chunks.push(e.data);
    }
    
      stop.onclick = function() {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
        console.log("recorder stopped");
        record.style.background = "#5bc0de";
        record.style.color = "white";
      }
    
      mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
        console.log("recorder stopped");
      
        const clipName = prompt('Enter a name for your sound clip');
        const clipContainer = document.createElement('article');
        const clipLabel = document.createElement('p');
        const audio = document.createElement('audio');
        const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
      
        clipContainer.classList.add('clip');
      
        audio.setAttribute('controls', '');
        deleteButton.innerHTML = "Delete";
        clipLabel.innerHTML = clipName;
      
        clipContainer.appendChild(audio);
        clipContainer.appendChild(clipLabel);
        clipContainer.appendChild(deleteButton);
        soundClips.appendChild(clipContainer);
      
        const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: chunks[0].type });
        chunks = [];
        const audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        audio.src = audioURL;
      
        deleteButton.onclick = function(e) {
        let evtTgt = e.target;
        evtTgt.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(evtTgt.parentNode);
        }
      }
    }) 

    // Error callback
    .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('The following getUserMedia error occurred: ' + err);
    }
    );

    } else {
    console.log('getUserMedia not supported on your browser!');
    } 
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use a bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) which would bundle your JavaScript code before it gets loaded by the browser. A bundler's job is to locate all the external packages on your disk (looking them up in the `node_modules` directory) to bundle them into one file (or sometimes more files) which can then be loaded by the browser.

Or you could use a service like [JSPM](https://jspm.org/) which allows you to load external packages directly from the web.

```
import { MediaRecorder, register } from 'https://jspm.dev/extendable-media-recorder';
import { connect } from 'https://jspm.dev/extendable-media-recorder-wav-encoder';
```

While JSPM is nice for building quick prototypes I would recommend using something like webpack in the long run.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I think I managed to bundle the code with webpack, and I wrote a new javascript application following this tutorial [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Using_the_MediaStream_Recording_API) and your exemple here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56452667/typescript-record-and-play-raw-pcm-audio/56453655#56453655). But now I have a new error : " Cannot access 't' before initialization". I will post above the code of my new application. Could someone explain what I did wrong? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It's difficult to tell since Webpack (or presumably Terser) is changing the variable names which means `t` could be anything. But I assume it's the `mediaStream` variable. Could you try to removing it and instead take the `stream` which you get as a function argument?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot again. I removed the variable 'mediaStream' and now I have no more the error. Here there is the new code:
`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
    .then(function(stream) {
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {mimeType: 'audio/wav'});`
But now the player who gives me the possibility to listen and download the file recorded (that normally is created after the button 'stop' is pressed) has disappeared. In addition I have a new error: 
"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_REQUEST_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE".
Someone could say what I did wrong?thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about the error but the audio element is probably invisible because of a typo here: `audio.setAttribute('controles', '');` should be `audio.setAttribute('controls', '');` without the "e".

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! It works now...The only thing is that the file exported is a .txt file. If I'm not wrong, I think there is a problem related to the fact that the variable "data" (inside the eventListener) has not been defined, or in any case it's not linked to the Blob. I guess I will have to modify something here, but I don't know what: 
`const blob = new Blob(chunks);
const audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
audio.src = audioURL;`

Comment: You can re-set the mime type of the first chunk to be sure it gets picked up correctly. `const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: chunks[0].type });`. But since you don't use the `timeslice` param you can also simplify this a bit to `const blob = chunks[0];`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works now !! I will modify the code above ... Thanks again, you really helped me a lot !

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'm happy to hear that it works now.