error referencing extendable-media-recorder using jsdelivr
my goal is to record audio and upload the audio as mp3 to firebase ;
i started following this : https://franzeus.medium.com/record-audio-in-js-and-upload-as-wav-or-mp3-file-to-your-backend-1a2f35dea7e8
it has the following code :
import {MediaRecorder, register} from 'extendable-media-recorder';
i searched for extendable-media-recorder on a cdn and found : https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/extendable-media-recorder
however , when i try to use extendable-media-recorder i get an error :
_regeneratorRuntime is undefined :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mark')
    at bundle.js:653:70
    at bundle.js:652:73
    at bundle.js:4:80
    at bundle.js:1:1

i have tried making a brand new .html file and using the following code :
<script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/extendable-media-recorder@9.2.4/build/es5/bundle.min.js "></script>
i have tried using the esm option from cdn in a brand new .html file :
<script type="module">
import extendableMediaRecorder from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/extendable-media-recorder@9.2.4/+esm'
</script>

i am expecting there to be no error message for just including a package

i found on this answer that i can use jspm.dev instead of jsdelivr : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68986049/25584927
import {
  MediaRecorder,
  register
} from 'https://jspm.dev/extendable-media-recorder';
import {
  connect
} from 'https://jspm.dev/extendable-media-recorder-wav-encoder';

and here is a full working demo based on this question Problems installing and importing npm package 'extendable-media-recorder' and this blog https://franzeus.medium.com/record-audio-in-js-and-upload-as-wav-or-mp3-file-to-your-backend-1a2f35dea7e8 that records audio as wave and converts it to mp3 and lets you name and play back recordings
<button id="record">record</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
<div class="sound-clips"></div>
<script type="module">
  import {
    MediaRecorder,
    register
  } from 'https://jspm.dev/extendable-media-recorder';
  import {
    connect
  } from 'https://jspm.dev/extendable-media-recorder-wav-encoder';
  import breezystacklamejs from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@breezystack/lamejs@1.2.7/+esm'
  const record = document.getElementById('record');
  const stop = document.getElementById('stop');
  const soundClips = document.querySelector('.sound-clips');
  (async () => {
    let mr = await html_recorder_media()
    record.onclick = function() {
      html_recorder_media_start(mr)
      record.style.background = "red";
      record.style.color = "black";
    }
    stop.onclick = async function() {
      const blob_mp3 = await html_recorder_media_stop(mr)
      record.style.background = "#5bc0de";
      record.style.color = "white";
      console.log("recorder stopped");
      const clipName = prompt('Enter a name for your sound clip');
      const clipContainer = document.createElement('article');
      const clipLabel = document.createElement('p');
      const audio = document.createElement('audio');
      const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
      clipContainer.classList.add('clip');
      audio.setAttribute('controls', '');
      deleteButton.innerHTML = "Delete";
      clipLabel.innerHTML = clipName;
      clipContainer.appendChild(audio);
      clipContainer.appendChild(clipLabel);
      clipContainer.appendChild(deleteButton);
      soundClips.appendChild(clipContainer);
      const audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob_mp3);
      audio.src = audioURL;
      deleteButton.onclick = function(e) {
        let evtTgt = e.target;
        evtTgt.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(evtTgt.parentNode);
      }
    }
  })();

  function html_recorder_media_start(mr) {
    let AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    let audioContext = new AudioContext();
    let {
      media_recorder
    } = mr;
    media_recorder.start();
  }
  async function html_recorder_media_stop(mr) {
    let {
      media_recorder,
      chunks
    } = mr;
    let type = "stop";
    return await new Promise((resolve) => {
      html_event_listener(media_recorder, type, async function on_stop() {
        html_event_listener_remove(media_recorder, type, on_stop);
        let blob = new Blob(chunks, {
          type: chunks[0].type,
        });
        let blob_mp3 = await html_wav_to_mp3(blob);
        list_remove_all(chunks);
        resolve(blob_mp3);
      });
      media_recorder.stop();
    });
  }

  function html_event_listener(element, type, lambda) {
    element.addEventListener(type, lambda);
  }

  function html_event_listener_remove(element, type, on_load) {
    element.removeEventListener(type, on_load);
  }
  async function html_wav_to_mp3(wav_blob) {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function() {
        let arrayBuffer = this.result;
        let wavDecoder = breezystacklamejs.WavHeader.readHeader(new DataView(arrayBuffer), );
        let wavSamples = new Int16Array(arrayBuffer, wavDecoder.dataOffset, wavDecoder.dataLen / 2, );
        let mp3Encoder = new breezystacklamejs.Mp3Encoder(wavDecoder.channels, wavDecoder.sampleRate, 128, );
        let mp3Buffer = mp3Encoder.encodeBuffer(wavSamples);
        let mp3Data = mp3Encoder.flush();
        let mp3BufferWithHeader = new Uint8Array(mp3Buffer.length + mp3Data.length, );
        mp3BufferWithHeader.set(mp3Buffer, 0);
        mp3BufferWithHeader.set(mp3Data, mp3Buffer.length);
        let mp3Blob = new Blob([mp3BufferWithHeader], {
          type: "audio/mp3",
        });
        resolve(mp3Blob);
      };
      reader.onerror = function(e) {
        reject(e);
      };
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(wav_blob);
    });
  }
  async function html_recorder_media() {
    let port = await connect();
    await register(port);
    if (!navigator.mediaDevices || !navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
      error("getUserMedia not supported on your browser!");
    }
    let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
    });
    let media_recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
      mimeType: "audio/wav",
    });
    let result = {
      media_recorder,
      chunks: [],
    };
    media_recorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
      result.chunks.push(e.data);
    };
    return result;
  }

  function list_remove_all(nexts) {
    nexts.length = 0;
  }
</script>

